# Java/IntelliJ keep classes in another folder but in the same package

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there a way to keep your classes separated in different folders without keeping them in a different package?

I have a collection of about 40 classes, and I do want all of them to be in the same package, but I want a way to visually group them so it's a bit easier to navigate as this grows in size.

Is there a way to do this with IntelliJ? In Java in general?

The reason I don't want sub-packages is as follows:

`Foo` in package `Foo`:

```
package Foo;
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bar.FooBar(); //<--compile error
    }
}
```

and `Bar` in package `Foo.Bar`:

```
package Foo.Bar;

public class Bar {
    static void FooBar() {}
}
```

Comment: Wait, *why* do you want them to be in the same package?  There comes a time when it makes more sense to start moving things apart.  The reason for that is relying on the default visibility is OK for things that are related but if you want to start separating them, that reliance on the default visibility starts to make less sense.

Comment: @Makoto, a fair point (+1). Mostly to hide implementation details and prevent unintended dependencies. It does make sense to start breaking it down to smaller parts at some point, with the more "implementy" (original word there) packages not really mattering if they have members with public access because they won't be of much use outside of the jar... and if they are... it shouldn't matter as long as our public interface is well-defined from the start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have more than one source classpath with the same package structure, you can do this.

In IntelliJ, you can simply make a new folder and then mark that folder as a Source folder. (Right Click folder -> Mark Directory As -> Sources Root). Again, as long as the package structure is the same, all classes in the same packages will end up together.

Comment: I don't have this option. Do you know why it might not be available for me?

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ do you have? As far as I know, as long as you're right clicking on a folder in the Project window, the "Mark Directory As" option should appear.

Comment: I misunderstood. There is an option "mark directory as" for packages, but this only has the option to exclude it. Adding a file to the same directory src is usually in allows this.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `maven` in IntelliJ, you could use the `build-helper-maven-plugin` in your `build` section of your pom file like this:

```
<build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
         <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.9.1</version>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <id>src</id>
               <phase>generate-sources</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>add-source</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                  <sources>
                     <source>../your/additional/source/path</source>
                  </sources>
               </configuration>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

This way you can separate your code into multiple logical folders while using the same package in the project, and maven will take care of grouping them all together when you run any maven command.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with Favorites in IntelliJ. They would be grouped visually, but would remain in the same package folder; however, not suggesting this as being a good design approach.